# How do I use Process.Start to open a word file (Path with Spaces)?

Tags: c#, process.start

The file is in the directory but the spaces cause this error:

```
string outfile = @"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\New folder (4)\outFile.doc";    
Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", outfile);
```

Shows me this message

[image]

and
this

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided that Winword.exe is your default application for Word documents, all you need is to specify your document's path in the process Filename property as follows

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Someone\Documents\Path With Spaces\Word.docx";
        p.Start();
```

Tested in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Answer (score 3):

Since your path contains spaces and normally, program arguments are separated by spaces, your `outfile` is interpreted as 3 different arguments. You need to enclose the path in quotes to make it work.

```
string outfile = @"""C:\Users\hp\Desktop\New folder (4)\outFile.doc""";
```

Quotes have to be doubled, because you used verbatim string.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works :D
but doesn't @ interact with the whole string as one unit ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by saying "interact", @ does say, that whole string is verbatim. I'm under the impression that you are missing the fact, that quotes used for `string` declaration are not the quotes used for passing the arguments to the process.

Comment: but am i need additional quotes to pass the path to the process ?
as i was reading about the 'process' the second argument is the file path only

Answer (score 0):

```
    string outfile = "\"C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\New folder (4)\\outFile.doc\"";    
Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", outfile);
```